# How to get Pins categories from IMFMediaSource

Tags: c++, com, directshow, ms-media-foundation

I need to iterate the IMFMediaSource pins and get the specific category name of each one of them, I am working in win 8, using the cpp interface of media foundation.

I saw that theres a IBaseFilter::EnumPins function for IBaseFilter, but IMFMediaSource dont support IBaseFilter interface :

`CComPtr<IBaseFilter> pFilter;

HRESULT hr = m_pMediaSource->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IBaseFilter), (void **)&pFilter);`

fails with NO_INTERFACE errorcode :(

how can I get the pins categories from a Media Source??

Answer (score 1):

This does not work because it does not have to work. `IMFMediaSource` belongs to Media Foundation and `IBaseFilter` belongs to DirectShow. The different APIs don't have to share or otherwise duplicate implementation. Media Foundation objects don't even have pins to start with.

Since there can be no answer to the question asked, the only solution here is to step back and review what exactly you are trying to achieve in first place.

Comment: thanks for commenting, Media foundation has some kind of pin structure, you can set streams by indexes with IMFTransfom. so theres no way of differentiate streams by Preview/Stills/Video categories?

Comment: MF has its own shiny new model with presentation descriptors, streams and stuff. No pins. No Categories. DirectShow interfaces are not applicable.